# Advantage of using lazyload?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So i stumble on this component called [lazyload](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/getting-started).

What does it do and advantage and disadvantage of using it ??

Just curious about it because i watch some of john papa's videos and he keep mentioning it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They idea of lazy load is that you only load something when you need it.

For example: at startup of your application you might not need a library to validate your form fields. (you only need it when someone actualy fills in a form and submits it).

Lazy loading makes sure its only loaded when needed.

The Plus:

- Reduced start/load times & size.
- Packages/data that are not used by the current user, will not be loaded.

Minus:

- You have to have more seperate packages you can't minify and bundle them together.
- More request to the server (because you can't bundle them).
- could have a load on first use experience, the first time user does something the application needs to load some extra stuff.

## conclusion & advice

So consider the size and the lifecycle of your application. If the application is small and you package all in one. probably the simplest approach would be to package everything in one. it's a bit of a longer load time, but after that the javascript gets cached in the browser anyways so it doesn't matter after first load.

Reasons you want to lazy load:

- You want to be able to update seperate parts of the applications (thus not bundle it)
- Application becoming problematically big. you want to cut it up in smaller parts.
- You don't bundle your javascript files (great example here before angular was requirejs).
- You have a lot of different types of users using the system each with completely different set of scripts.
- Every page uses completely different set of javascript. (not likely when you use angular)

Comment: thanks for the great explanation maybe i will stick to the normal way of handling packages. And as you've said in your conclusion "You have a lot of different types of users using the system each with completely different set of scripts.
" which my project right now don't have. Cheers